# mysql command prints out help menu when ran from java program

Tags: java, mysql, shell

my mysql command is being ran from inside a java program and prints out the help menu, but when I run the exact same command in terminal it works fine. Not quite sure why.

```
String shellCommand = "mysql -u root < " + destinationDirectory+"/"+ filename;
executeCommand(shellCommand);
```

here's the execute command method:

```
public static void executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process process;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "COMMAND: "+ command);

        process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(output.toString());
}
```

EDIT:
Here's another approach but it gives me this error I tried running actual mysql commands instead of using hibernate as I originally was but still to no avail. The wait is in there to give the restore some time to get to where it hangs due to locks and then close the program so the locks and database are freed:

```
// JDBC driver name and database URL
  final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
  final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://" + HOST + "/" + DATABASE;


   Connection conn = null;
   final Statement stmt;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
        Services.endServices();

        Thread progress = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

              try {
                  String sql = "source /mount/mf/outbox/b3sql.sql";
                  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                  System.out.println("Database loaded successfully...");

              }catch(SQLException se){
              //Handle errors for JDBC
              se.printStackTrace();
           }
        }

        };
        progress.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);
        System.exit(0); 
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{

            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
      }// do nothing
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
```

-

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'source /mount/mf/outbox/b3sql.sql'
```

Comment: With this approach you can only execute SQL commands, not mysql commands. Have a look at b3sql.sql, the commands in there.

Comment: So should I just read each line of SQL command from my .sql file and execute that as a statement? or is there a better way to initiate the restore database from inside the code while the program is running and have it continue executing afterwards?

Comment: You can try that, but I don't know what commands are inside b3sql.sql.  If you had followed my instructions in my answer, your java program would have executed mysql and sourced b3sql.sql.   Why don't you run it from the command-line if this is a one time restore of your database?

Comment: I don't think its a one time restore in the sense of it'll never be done again, its a function of my program to be able to restore/load any old sql file lying around while the program is up and then to restart the program

Comment: When you tried my answer, you just said "it doesn't restore".  If you added the error handling, you should have seen either the standard output or the standard error of the script.  Please give an example of such script.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell understands input redirection "<", but Java is not starting a shell!  Try this:

```
String shellCommand[] =
      {"/usr/bin/mysql", "-h", "127.0.0.1",
       "-u", "myDBuser",
       "--password=aMeHoElA",
       "-e",  "source /here/is/myscript.sql" };
executeCommand(shellCommand);
```

and modify (command is now a string array):

```
public static void executeCommand(String command[]) {
```

and don't forget to read the error output, it would have helped you:

```
    BufferedReader ereader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    String eline = "";
    while ((eline = ereader.readLine())!= null) {
        output.append("ERROR: " + eline + "\n");
```

MySQL needs "source myscript.txt" as a single parameter.  When you put it in a string with the rest of the command, Java passes it as two arguments, impossible to avoid.

Comment: so now it doesn't print out the menu anymore, but it also doesn't replace the current database like it is supposed to.

Comment: Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: What happens if you try that from a shell?

Comment: From a shell it worked, but mysql needs  "source myscript.txt" as a single parameter.  When you put it in a string, Java passes it as two arguments, impossible to avoid.

Comment: it still doesn't restore the database. I'm not sure why it works in terminal and not irl. Also not sure how to take down the current database if I have to even do that.

Comment: well currently I have a program that is running and connected to the database that I'm trying to restore while the program is running. Even when I close the session it still hangs trying to restore the database. The only way to restore the database is to turn the program off and then run the command but how can I turn the program itself off when it is restoring the database?

Comment: Sorry John, I don't understand a word of what you're saying.  You are trying to restore a database?  Is this a disaster recovery?  The only way to restore the database is to turn of the program that is restoring the database?  Again: show me the program, that I'll understand.

Comment: so the program has a restore database function which should let you pick a .sql file that you have already backed up to restore. I was struggling to execute the restore since the program itself picks the file to restore. I've edited my original question to show my new approach